# Corresponding values of a parameter in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working in SageMath (Python-based), I am quite new to programming and I have the following question. In my computations I have a quadratic form: x^TAx = b  , where the matrix A is defined already as a symmetric matrix, and x is defined as

```
import itertools
X = itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n)
for x in X:
    x = vector(x)
    print x
```

as all combination of [0,1] repeated n times. I got a set of values for b the following way:

```
import itertools
X = itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n)
results = []
for x in X:
    x = vector(x)
    x = x.row()
    v = x.transpose()
    b = x * A * v
    results.append(b[0, 0])
```

And then I defined:

```
U = set(results)
U1 = sorted(U)
A = []
for i in U1:
    U2 = round(i, 2)
    A.append(U2)
```

So I have a sorted set to get a few minimal values of my results. I need to extract minimal values from the set and identify what particular x is corresponding to each value of b. I heard that I can use dictionary method and define preimages in there, but I am really struggling to define my dictionary as {key: value}. Could someone help me please, solve the problem or give me the idea of what direction should I think in? Thank you.

Comment: Whats `vector(x)`?

Comment: it makes sure x is defined as a vector, without that it is just a tuple